# How to bind elements of the same index in numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to make a function that bind the elements of the same index of two different subarrays in one numpy array.
If the input is, for example, `input = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`, I want to have it `output =[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]` or something similar. The number of subarray can varry (input is **input*)
I would either sum the newly binded elements together at the end. For example, [1+4, 2+5, 3+6].
I know a work around but I would like to know if there are some built-in functions to do this.

What I've tried
-`numpy.add()` function requires two numpy arrays so this won't work

- for x,y in zip (*input[i] for i in len(lists)) gives an error of insufficient arguments

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to do?  Take a look at this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in the end you are interested in the sum of elements, I would simply do:

```
import numpy as np
input = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
np.sum(input, axis=0)
```

ouput = array([5, 7, 9])

If you do want to have the intermediate array at some point, you just need a transposition:

```
input.T
```

output = array([[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]])